# Price wrongly updating

Tags: java, android, counter

my total price for the single Item in the Cart is updatin wrong. If I increase the quantity and reduce it, then happens following:

> Increase quantity 1=4,10; 2=4,10; 3=8,20; 4=12,30; Reduce quantity: from 4(16,30) to 3 = 16,40; 2 = 12,30; 1=8,20;

But the total price of all items is correct.

```
public class CartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartViewHolder> {

private List<Order> listData = new ArrayList<>();
private Cart cart;

public CartAdapter(List<Order> listData, Cart cart) {
    this.listData = listData;
    this.cart = cart;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public CartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(cart);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_layout, parent, false);
    return new CartViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CartViewHolder holder, final int position) {


    holder.btn_quantity.setNumber(listData.get(position).getQuantity());
    holder.btn_quantity.setOnValueChangeListener(new ElegantNumberButton.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(ElegantNumberButton view, int oldValue, int newValue) {

            Locale locale = new Locale("de", "DE");
            NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
            double price = (Double.parseDouble(listData.get(position).getPrice()))*(Double.parseDouble(listData.get(position).getQuantity()));
            //int price = (Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getQuantity()));
            holder.txt_price.setText(fmt.format(price));
            holder.txt_cart_name.setText(listData.get(position).getProductName());

            Order order = listData.get(position);
            order.setQuantity(String.valueOf(newValue));
            new Database(cart).updateCart(order);

            double total = 0;
            List<Order> orders = new Database(cart).getCarts();
            for (Order item:orders)
                total+=(Double.parseDouble(order.getPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt(item.getQuantity()));

            cart.txtTotalPrice.setText(fmt.format(total));
        }
    });

    Locale locale = new Locale("de", "DE");
    NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
    double price = (Double.parseDouble(listData.get(position).getPrice()))*(Double.parseDouble(listData.get(position).getQuantity()));
    //int price = (Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getQuantity()));
    holder.txt_price.setText(fmt.format(price));
    holder.txt_cart_name.setText(listData.get(position).getProductName());
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listData.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably, the problem is in the sequence of code, you should put this code:

```
Order order = listData.get(position);
order.setQuantity(String.valueOf(newValue));
new Database(cart).updateCart(order);
```

in the starting of:

```
public void onValueChange(ElegantNumberButton view, int oldValue, int newValue) {
  // event listener code
}
```

this block.

i hope it helps :)

Comment: as you told "Increase quantity 1=4,10; 2=4,10; 3=8,20; 4=12,30; Reduce quantity: from 4(16,30) to 3 = 16,40; 2 = 12,30; 1=8,20;", clearly each quantity is showing the value of previously entered quantity, which tells that there must be some problem in sequence of code, so if my answer doesn't work, try checking the sequence.

Comment: by the way i loved your coding style, but there's a tip, in programming, programmers generally follow DRY principle, i.e. Do not Reapeat Yourself, and as in your code, you have used NumberFormat and Locale in eventListener which makes every item, there will be a new instance of each, you could instead make a FINAL NumberFormat in method onBindViewHolder() and use the same instance again and again, or even create a private one for whole class, it definitely reduces memory usage and improves efficiency.